# Converting movieclip into sprite/bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, sprite, movieclip

I have expanded class, movieclip type. It's built from some other movieclips and in the process it uses them.
So I have a question. To lower the memory, how can I convert the output effect of this movieclip into a sprite? I mean it's appeareance changes partially, since all children change their look oh their own.

How do I do this in the best way? And is it easy to do?

Comment: You can make its parent a `Sprite` but it won't improve the performance much. You can try to set the `cacheAsBitmap` property to true if the contents of that `MovieClip` change infrequently, otherwise it has no benefits.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to go into the MovieClips and optimise them by hand in the Flash IDE (smoothing, breaking groups etc). If you need to improve performance on mobile you could try 'blitting' the movieclip to a bitmap, but that would actually increase memory usage.